# Trying to use android studio to install an apk. Getting "Client not ready yet.."

Tags: android, apk

So I am trying to install an app called Live2d wallpaper on my android, and I can run the app to get it to install on an emulator, but when I try to run it on my android version 7.0 on my samsung galaxy s8+, I get this error:

```
09/17 14:35:31: Launching Live 2d wallpaper
$ adb push C:\Users\Levi\Desktop\Live2D_SDK_Android_2.0.06_1_en\out\production\liveWallpaper\liveWallpaper.apk /data/local/tmp/jp.live2d.sample
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/jp.live2d.sample"
Success


Client not ready yet..
```

I'm new to this kind of thing, but I would appreciate any kind of help. I've already set developer options on and also turned on usb debugging, but I don't know what else to do.